# Статистика бота на discord.py

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Помогите пожалуйста сделать похожую команду как вот тут[image: Вот сама картинка команды]

Я пытался это сделать сам, но у меня не получалось вычислять сколько серверов, пользователей и голосовых каналом смотрит мой бот, у меня получилось сделать только пинг бота, когда он был запущен и ембед :(

**Кто поможет, тому буду очень сильно благодарен! Сразу говорю, я новичок в пайтоне!**
Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: В данный момент вы просите не помочь, а фактически написать за вас код. Что именно у вас не получается? Отправить сообщение? Посчитать количество серверов? Нажмите [**править**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1363679/edit) под вашим вопросом и обозначьте конкретную проблему, которую вам не удается решить самостоятельно.

Comment: Хорошо, я изменил свой вопрос, теперь я думаю мне смогут помочь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Я пытался это сделать сам, но у меня не получалось вычислять сколько
> серверов

Да там и вычислять-то ничего не надо. Просто один раз загуглить что-то вроде *"как получить количество серверов бота discord py"*, либо научиться работать с документацией, где все свойства и методы всех объектов расписаны максимально подробно.

**Рекомендую почитать** [**краткое руководство**](https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/using_docs.md#%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-discord-py) - все, что я пишу ниже сразу станет понятно.

---

Открываем [**свойства и методы бота**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot#discord.ext.commands.Bot) и видим, что здесь есть все почти все необходимое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На каждый элемент списка можно нажать и посмотреть что этот объект из себя представляет.

---

Видим, что свойство `bot.guilds` возвращает список (`list`) серверов бота

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таким образом, количество серверов вы можете получить просто применив к списку встроенный метод `len()`

```
guilds_count = len(bot.guilds)
```

Тоже самое с голосовыми соединениями (`bot.voice_clients`) и пользователями (`bot.users`).

---

Каналы находятся на серверах, а это значит, получать их количество нужно именно из объектов серверов.

Вбиваем в поиск документации ключевое слово `guild` и открываем [**список свойств сервера**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видим здесь свойство `channels` - не сложно догадаться, что это список каналов сервера.

Поскольку посчитать количество каналов нужно для всех серверов - воспользуемся циклом `for`:

```
channels_count = 0
for guild in bot.guilds:
    channels_count += len(guild.channels)
```

Точно также можно посчитать количество **всех** участников серверов, так как `bot.users` возвращает только доступных боту пользователей

```
members_count = 0
for guild in bot.guilds:
    members_count += len(guild.members)
```

Comment: Вов, спасибо вам большое за помощь, я вам очень признателен, удачи вам!