# Не запускается команда на Discord - Python

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

У меня есть маленький код бота **Discord**:

```
#Статистика дискoрд бота МОЕГО
@bot.command()
async def stat(ctx, user: discord.Member=None):
    if user == None:
        user = ctx.author
    await ctx.send(
    embed = discord.Embed(
    title='Статистика LiteBot',
    description=f'**Основная**\n**Серверов:** {len(bot.guilds)}\n**Пользователей:** {len(guild.members)}\n**Каналов:** {len(guild.channels)}\n**Платформа**\n**Задержка:** {round(bot.latency * 1000)}mc\n**Запущен**: <t:1635770881:D>',
    color= 0xff9900))
```

Он идеально работал, но после того, как я добавил это:

```
{len(bot.channels)}
```

И вот это:

```py
{len(bot.members)}
```

Команда перестала работать, а в консоли никаких ошибок нету. Не знаю, как исправить.

Comment: Я вам недавно кидал [**скриншот**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7t1w.png) свойств и методов бота. Где вы там увидели свойства `channels` и `members`??? В [**предыдущем ответе**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1363700/373173) я уже писал что эти свойства принадлежат объекту сервера, а не бота и даже написал как их получить. Зачем плодить одинаковые вопросы?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Статистика бота на discord.py](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1363679/%d0%a1%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-discord-py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@bot.command()
async def stat(ctx, member: discord.Member=None):
    member = ctx.author if not member else member
    bot_members = sum([len(guild.members) for guild in bot.guilds])
    await ctx.send(
    embed = discord.Embed(
    title='Статистика LiteBot',
    description=f'**Основная**\n**Серверов:** {len(bot.guilds)}\n**Пользователей:** {bot_members}\n**Каналов:** {len(guild.channels)}\n**Платформа**\n**Задержка:** {round(bot.latency * 1000)}mc\n**Запущен**: <t:1635770881:D>',
    color= 0xff9900))
```